# Missing symbol: cuDevicePrimaryCtxRelease vs cuDevicePrimaryCtxRelease_v2

Tags: linux, cuda, linker-errors, cuda-context, cuda-driver

I'm trying to build the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda.h>

int main() {
    const char* str;

    auto status = cuInit(0);
    cuGetErrorString(status, &str);
    std::cout << "status = " << str << std::endl;

    int device_id = 0;
    CUcontext primary_context_id;
    status = cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain(&primary_context_id, device_id);
    cuGetErrorString(status, &str);
    std::cout << "status = " << str << std::endl;

    status = cuDevicePrimaryCtxRelease(device_id);
    cuGetErrorString(status, &str);
    std::cout << "status = " << str << std::endl;
}
```

Compilation always goes fine; but, with CUDA 10.2, linking works, while with CUDA 11.2, I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: a.o: in function `main':
a.cpp:(.text+0xcc): undefined reference to `cuDevicePrimaryCtxRelease_v2'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Note: I'm using Devuan Beowulf with driver version 440.82 (have not installed a new driver for CUDA 11.2).

Comment: @talonmies: See my edit and partial answer.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I think I have an idea of why this happens.

This is about how `cuDevicePrimaryCtxRelease()` is defined. Let's run:

```
grep PrimaryCtxRelease /usr/local/cuda/include/cuda.h | grep -v "^ "
```

In CUDA 10.2, we get:

```
CUresult CUDAAPI cuDevicePrimaryCtxRelease(CUdevice dev);
```

while in CUDA 11.2, we get:

```
#define cuDevicePrimaryCtxRelease           cuDevicePrimaryCtxRelease_v2
CUresult CUDAAPI cuDevicePrimaryCtxRelease(CUdevice dev);
```

That is, the API name has changed, but the header file leaves an alias to the new name. (And that's a confusing piece of code, I would say.)

Now, let's peer into the object files I get in the two different versions of CUDA, using `objdump -t | c++filt | grep cu`. With CUDA 10.2, it's:

```
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 cuInit
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 cuGetErrorString
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 cuDevicePrimaryCtxRelease
```

while with CUDA 11.2, it's:

```
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 cuInit
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 cuGetErrorString
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 cuDevicePrimaryCtxRelease_v2
```

(note the `_v2`).

so it's probably the case that the installed driver only contains the non-`_v2` symbol, hence the undefined symbol.

What I would still appreciate help with is how to work around this issue other than by updating the driver.

Comment: link against the libcuda stub provided by CUDA 11.2 (on that machine/setup) rather than the actual libcuda provided by the 440.xx driver

Comment: @RobertCrovella: 1. Do you mean `lib64/stubs/libcuda.so`? 2. Is there a way to get CMake to prefer that stub over the system driver? 3. Is there a performance penalty for doing this?

Comment: 1. Yes.  2. Don't know.  3. No.  Also note that such a binary, built against CUDA 11.2, is not going to run on your machine that has the 440.xx driver.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Oh :-(